# Glob renaming in bash

Tags: bash, echo, space, glob, mv

I'm fairly new to bash so sorry if this is kind of a basic question.  I was trying to rename a bunch of mp3 files to prepend `1-` to their filenames, and `mv *.mp3 1-*.mp3` didn't work unfortunately.   So I tried to script it, first with echo to test the commands:

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do echo mv \'$f\' \'1-$f\'; done
```

Which seems to output the commands that I like, so I removed the echo, changing the command to

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do mv \'$f\' \'1-$f\'; done
```

Which failed.  Next I tried piping the commands onward like so

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do echo mv \'$f\' \'1-$f\'; done | /bin/sh
```

Which worked, but if anyone could enlighten me as to why the middle command doesn't work I would be interested to know.  Or if there is an more elegant one-liner that would do what I wanted, I would be interested to see that too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to change the command to

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do mv "$f" "1-$f"; done
```

Otherwise you would pass something like `'file1.mp3'` and `'1-file1.mp3'` to `mv` (including the single quotes).

Comment: i intended to include the single quotes, because otherwise i would need to escape all the spaces with backslashes.  mv does not mind the quotes.  however, the filenames can also have ' in them (and " for that matter).

Comment: You don't need to escape the spaces when you use double quotes around `$f`. It's also no problem if the file name contains single or double quotes.

Answer (score 9):

Dry run:

```
rename -n 's/^/1-/' *.mp3
```

Remove the `-n` if it looks correct to run the command. `man rename` for details.

Comment: This works on Debian but not on CentOS where the rename command does not follow this syntax and is much less powerful.